# How to retrieve the health data from samsung watch via mobile application?

Tags: java, android, wear-os, watch, samsung-mobile

I have to work on a task in which i have to retrieve the health data from the samsung watch, but i don't know from where i can start. I have a lot of questions;

1. Can i directly fetch the data from the samsung watch with a custom application?
2. I need to create two applications, one for the watch and second for the mobile?
3. From where i can get the samsung sdk?

```
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.healthdata:health-data-api:1.1.0-alpha01'
implementation group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '30.1.1-jre'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:17.1.0'
implementation files('libs/samsung-health-service-v1.4.0.jar')
implementation files('libs/sdk-v1.0.0.jar')
```

but when i am trying below dependency to implement getting error
implementation 'com.samsung.android.sdk.healthdata: 1.0.5'
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to do is to use the Health Connect described at : https://developer.android.com/health-and-fitness/guides/health-connect/develop/get-started
This way you can retrieve the health data.
I am looking for an alternate option of retrieving the heart rate data using Health services on wear os. Stuck at transferring the data from wear os to mobile app.